# Combobox refresh gives Value '' couldn't be converted validation error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i'm new to WPF. I have an application with multiple tabs. In one tab I can insert data into a table in the database. In another tab I have a combobox with itemsource of the table mentioned earlier. I want to update the combobox items when user want to chose from the combobox./

I tried with the GotFocus property in the following way:

```
private void ComboBoxOperatingPoints_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ThisViewModel.UpdateModel();
        }
```

Updatemodel function contains the following:

```
this.OperatingPoints = new ObservableCollection<Operating_Point>(new OperatingPointRepository().GetAll());
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("OperatingPoints");
```

The combobox bindind in the XAML :

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBoxOperatingPoints_SelectionChanged" 
                      x:Name="ComboBoxOperatingPoints" 
                      GotFocus="ComboBoxOperatingPoints_GotFocus_1"
                      FontSize="30" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                      Margin="40,40,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      Width="200" 
                      Height="50"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding OperatingPoints}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="name"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding OperatingPointID,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="operating_point_id"
                      >
```

The combobox refresh, but gives validation error and I can't use it anymore after the first GotFocus event occured.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Finaly I changed the GotFocus event to DropDownOpened event and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a new `ObservableCollection` on every update.  You probably only want to create the `ObservableCollection` once, then replace it's contents in `UpdateModel`.  So, for example, in  your view model's constructor, instantiate the `OperatingPoints` collection:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public MyViweModel() {
        this.OperatingPoints = new ObservableCollection<Operating_Point>();
    }
}
```

Then, in `UpdateModel`:

```
public void UpdateModel() {
    this.OperatingPoints.Clear();

    foreach ( Operating_Point point in new OperatingPointRepository().GetAll() ) {
        this.OperatingPoints.Add(point);
    }
    NotifyPropertyChanged( "OperatingPoints" );
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using the wrong event because the refresh work just fine if I change the tab. But if I click to the combo box to select an item I can see in the profiler that the select statement which gets the data from the DB running multiple time until it caches. Can you suggest me another event for refreshind the viewmodel?

Comment: I tried the following and it seems that the got focus funtion runs twice when I click to the combobox :        private void ComboBoxOperatingPoints_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.ThisViewModel.UpdateModel();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: @TonyVitabile Please not, if you update an ObservableCollection (not replacing it with a new instance) it's not necessary to fire NotifyChanged events yourself - the ObservableCollection will do that. But as far as I know it will do it for every single operation (e.g. adding a single element), which results in a lot of GUI updates. So sometimes replacing the complete collection - and firing the NotifyChanged event for that - is the better solution.

Comment: @LóriNóda: I'm not sure why you're getting the event twice, though I suspect it might have to do with bubble routing (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx ).  You might want to consider updating the items in the `ComboBox` only when new items are inserted into the underlying table or existing items are modified.  You could do that by creating an event that you raise when you perform an action that would modify the model, then add a handler that updates the collection.